# floats in NumPy structured array and native string formatting with .format()

Tags: numpy, string-formatting, record

Can anyone tell me why this NumPy record is having trouble with Python's new-style string formatting?  All floats in the record choke on `"{:f}".format(record)`.

Thanks for your help!

```
In [334]: type(tmp)
Out[334]: numpy.core.records.record

In [335]: tmp
Out[335]: ('XYZZ', 2001123, -23.823917388916016)

In [336]: tmp.dtype
Out[336]: dtype([('sta', '|S6'), ('ondate', '<i8'), ('lat', '<f4')])

# Some formatting works fine
In [337]: '{0.sta:6.6s} {0.ondate:8d}'.format(tmp)
Out[337]: 'XYZZ    2001123'

# Any float has trouble
In [338]: '{0.sta:6.6s} {0.ondate:8d} {0.lat:11.6f}'.format(tmp)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/jkmacc/python/pisces/<ipython-input-338-e5f6bcc4f60f> in <module>()
----> 1 '{0.sta:6.6s} {0.ondate:8d} {0.lat:11.6f}'.format(tmp)

ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on the NumPy user mailing list under "floats coerced to string with  "{:f}".format() ?":

It seems that np.int64/32 and np.str inherit their respective native Python `__format__()`, but np.float32/64 doesn't get `__builtin__.float.__format__()`.  That's not intuitive, but I see now why this works:

```
In [8]: '{:6.6s} {:8d} {:11.6f}'.format(tmp.sta, tmp.ondate, float(tmp.lat))
Out[8]: 'XYZZ    2001123  -23.820000'
```

Thanks!

-Jon

**EDIT**:
np.float32/int32 inherits from native Python types **if** your system is 32-bit.  Same for 64-bit.  A mismatch will generate the same problem as the original post.